# change color base on status name in laravel

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I have post table in my laravel the table has status this name in the field, `approved` `decline` so I will like that in my blade view components when a post is `approved` I want give it a green background and when a post is `decline` I will like it to be red

so in my loop I have this

```
@foreach($posts as $post )
   {$post->body}

   {$post->status}

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

add

> bg-green

class to markup when your post->status is approved and add

> bg-red

when post->status is declined